# map for array and comparing at least one coincidence

Tags: javascript, arrays

In javascript, I have this situation:

`this.props.number` is always a number 0, 1,or 2

`this.props.columnas` is an array of objects like this:

```
[
    {value:'1',text:'AA'},
    {value:'2',text:'BB'},
    {value:'3',text:'CC'},
    {value:'4',text:'DD'},
    {value:'5',text:'EE'},
    {value:'6',text:'FF'},
    {value:'7',text:'GG'}
]
```

`selected` is an array of objects too like this:

`[{col:"2", ope:"", val:""}, {col:"5", ope:"", val:""}, {col:"7", ope:"", val:""}, ]`

And I have this code:

```
this.props.columnas.map(function(col){
    if(this.props.number == 0) {
        if (col.value == selected[0].col)
            disabledIndice = true
        else
            disabledIndice = false;
    }
    else if(this.props.number == 1) {
        if (col.value == selected[0].col || col.value == selected[1].col)
            disabledIndice = true
        else
            disabledIndice = false;
    }
    else if(this.props.number == 2) {
        if (col.value == selected[0].col || col.value == selected[1].col || col.value == selected[2].col)
            disabledIndice = true
        else
            disabledIndice = false;
    }
return <option value={col.value} disabled={disabledIndice}>{col.text}</option>
}.bind(this))}
```

(forget the `bind`. `function` and es5, I will use arrow functions anyway)

It's too long and it's not doing what I need to do. I want to use map again in `selected` to find which `col.value` is the same than the one stored on `selected`.

In the code above, I'm assuming that I'll have 3 objects for `selected`, but that's not always the case. Sometimes could be 1, 2 or 3 objects, that`s why the code is using those ìf` for each case (the numbers of objects is defined by `this.props.number`). That's ugly.

I've tried something like this:

```
this.props.columnas.map(function(col){
    indicesYaSeleccionado.map(function(item){
        if (col.value == item.col)
            disabledIndice = true
        else disabledIndice = false;
        });
    return <option key={constant.guid()} value={col.value} disabled={disabledIndice}>{col.text}</option>
}.bind(this))
```

But that I will always get `disabled`because I'm comparing each value, I need to set as `disabledIndice = true` at least in 1 coincidence.

Any tip? It was a long explanation, sorry.

Comment: Can you clearly mention what are you expecting the final result of the map to be?

Comment: that code is setting the options of an <select>. I need to set as `disable` every option that be equal to `selected[*].col`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've understand, you just have to see if the current `col` value is in the `selected.val` array.

```
this.props.columnas.map(function(col){

    let disabledIndice = 
        selected.findIndex(e => e.col === col.value) !== -1
        ? true : false

    return <option value={col.value} disabled={disabledIndice}>{col.text}</option>
}.bind(this))}
```

This code should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to re-add this.props to your contextualized variables, but this should cover it. And I tried to give you as many arrow functions as I could. Your return will break the code, but if used with something like React's JSX it should work fine.

```js
//removed this.props references for the sake of this example
const columnas = [
    {value:'1',text:'AA'},
    {value:'2',text:'BB'},
    {value:'3',text:'CC'},
    {value:'4',text:'DD'},
    {value:'5',text:'EE'},
    {value:'6',text:'FF'},
    {value:'7',text:'GG'}
];
//could be 0, 1, or 2
let curNum = 1
let selected = [{col:"2", ope:"", val:""}, {col:"5", ope:"", val:""}, {col:"7", ope:"", val:""}, ]

columnas.map( el => {
  let disabledIndice = selected.every( sel => el.value == sel.col ) ? 
    true : false;
  
    return <option key={constant.guid()} value={col.value} disabled={disabledIndice}>{col.text}</option>
}.bind(this))
});
```